# How to disable regular Arch Linux requests to their site?

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I have installed pure Arch Linux + GNOME 3. When my computer is turned on, Arch Linux regularly requests the site `www.archlinux.org`. Requests occurs every 1.5 and 3.5 minutes.

How can I disable these regular requests?

Comment: One potential source of such requests are NetworkManager connectivity checks: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Checking_connectivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This NetworkManager checked the internet connection.

To disable such a regular check of the Internet connection, you can edit the file:
`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity.conf`.

In this file, you can either comment out the line: `uri=http://www.archlinux.org/check_network_status.txt` or replace it with, for example, the following line: `uri=http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt`.

Details can be found in the documentation: [wiki.archlinux.org/NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Checking_connectivity)

To check the work of the NetworkManager at the moment, you can use the command: `systemctl status NetworkManager`.